# How to set the top of the page to underneath a top-fixed navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

If you go to [this](http://www.joehewett.co.uk/computing.html#1) page.
And click the side nav bar, it scrolls to a certain point on the page. However, the header of the section I'm trying to jump to, is hidden behind the fixed nav bar. How do I set it so the page will jump to a position in which the title of each section is visible?

Comment: provide some margin on top to the <div class="page-content">

Answer (score 0):

do not use `<br>`for margin bottom.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
body{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

or as inline css:

```
<body style="margin-top: 50px;"> ...
```

then you can remove the placeholders from your main content and your sidebar

Answer (score 0):

You can either add some padding-top to your sections title, or move your named anchors like:

```
a[name] {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about implementing class. Give #(num) class name in the body and call by #(num) in the link in the navbar that will redirect the the place you want. Why are you giving name='1' in anchor tag in place of href?

**This is Wrong Way**

```
<a name="1"></a>
```

You can see you content going inside top bar because of this method.

**Instead**

```
<div class="1">
    <h1>Computing Notes</h1>
</div>
```

Use href #value to call from anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="#1">Fundamentals of computer systems</a>
```